# Test if string contains single backslash?

Tags: actionscript-3

How would you do that?

I need to test if

a) the string contains two consecutive backslashes

b), if not, test if there is at least one backslash

```
if(test.indexOf("\\") >= 0) seems to hit on a string that's "ss\\ss", but I have a feeling that's incorrect. I think it's really just testing for 1 backslash.
```

And AS3 doesn't let you do if(test.indexOf("\") >= 0), as the single backslash escapes the rest of your code.

It's for testing the existance of either single or double backslashes in ID3 tags, as some editors use either as a delimeter for multiple tags within the one tag category eg genre: rock\pop, or rock\pop

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The single backslash escapes just the end-quotation mark, which makes the rest of your code part of the string. The way to specify a backslash in a string is to escape it using another backslash.

For example,

```
trace("Hello \\ World");   //Output: Hello \ World
trace("Hello \\\\ World"); //Output: Hello \\ World
```

Bottom line: When you want one backslash, the correct sequence in a string is `\\`. When you want two, just put the same sequence twice. In your case, the code would be something like this:

```
if(test.indexOf("\\\\") >= 0) {
    //test contains two backslashes
} else if(test.indexOf("\\") >= 0) {
    //test contains one backslash
}
```

You can also do this via Regular Expressions using the following code, if the number of backslashes doesn't matter to you.

```
if(/\\{1,2}/.test(string_to_test)) {
    //string_to_test contains one or two occurrences only.
}
```

Of course, if the number of backslashes doesn't matter (you want at least one), then just checking for a single backslash would also be enough

Answer (score -1):

try

if(s.indexOf("\\")>-1){

//there are two or more consecutive backslashes

} else if(s.indexOf("\")>-1){

// there is exactly one backslash

}

Comment: This is completely wrong. I suggest you take a look at your ActionScript skills once more.  It's almost as if you didn't read the question in the first place